# Update observable array of object in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to update one object in the observable array of object and get error :
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '[object Object]'.
How can I fix this?

```
export interface User {
    id: string
    name : string
    lastname: string
    email: string
    address: string
    password: string
}
```

```
allUsers = signal<Observable<User[]>>(new Observable())
```

```
this.allUsers.update(val => val.pipe(map(users => users.map((user:User)=>{
if(user.id == "65c2a622878dcef34ed569ad"){
  user.name = "new Name"
  user.lastname = "new Lastname"
  user.address = "new Address"
  user.password = "new Password"
 }
  return user
}))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the object in the array are `immutable`, so you can not directly modify their properties.

Instead, you need to return new object with the updated properties.

```
this.allUsers.update((val) =>
  val.pipe(
    map((users) =>
      users.map((user: User) => {
        if (user.id == "65c2a622878dcef34ed569ad") {
          return {
            ...user,
            name: "new Name",
            lastname: "new Lastname",
            address: "new Address",
            password: "new Password"
          };
        } else {
          return user;
         }
      })
    )
  )
);
```